# MySQL calculate over select not working with empty sub select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I'm trying to get the sum of a result in 5 different tables with just one SQL query. I have 5 tables and each table might contain a record that belongs to the order. The sum of all the records from the 5 tables determines the total order price.

Searching on this forum I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT
  OrderTotal.total + Shipping.amount + Service.amount - Gift.amount - RMA.total as TotalCosts
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total FROM order WHERE order_id=123456) OrderTotal
  (SELECT amount FROM shipping WHERE order_id=123456) Shipping,
  (SELECT amount FROM service WHERE order_id=123456) Service,
  (SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total FROM rma WHERE order_id=123456) RMA,
  (SELECT amount FROM gift WHERE order_id=123456) Gift
```

The problem I'm facing now is that when for example the last SELECT returns 0 rows, the total TotalCosts is not returned.

How to solve this?

Comment: Oke, my answer on my question is mentioned below. However I now need to do this in a loop which walks through all orders. So not giving it `order_id=123456` but list all orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using `UNION`?

```
SELECT  order_id, SUM(total) GrandTotal
FROM
        (
            SELECT  order_id, SUM(price * amount) AS total 
            FROM    `order` 
            WHERE   order_id = 123456
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  order_id, amount AS total 
            FROM    shipping 
            WHERE   order_id = 123456
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  order_id, amount AS total 
            FROM    service 
            WHERE order_id = 123456
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  order_id, SUM(price * amount) AS total 
            FROM    rma 
            WHERE   order_id = 123456
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  order_id, amount AS total 
            FROM    gift 
            WHERE   order_id=123456
        ) subTable
GROUP   BY order_id
```

Comment: Great! This is the answer!

Comment: This query also returns order_id "0" with a GrandTotal of "NULL". I don't understand why..

Comment: before the `GROUP BY` clause, add a condition `WHERE order_ID <> 0 GROUP BY order_id`` . kinda weired because you are only selecting `order_ID = 123456` inside union.

Comment: `WHERE order_id <> 0` did the job! Many thanks! Indeel weired why it's also returning order_id 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **IFNULL** function to solve

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(OrderTotal.total,0) + IFNULL(Shipping.amount + IFNULL(Service.amount - IFNULL(Gift.amount,0) - RMA.total as TotalCosts
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total FROM order WHERE order_id=123456) OrderTotal
  (SELECT amount FROM shipping WHERE order_id=123456) Shipping,
  (SELECT amount FROM service WHERE order_id=123456) Service,
  (SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total FROM rma WHERE order_id=123456) RMA,
  (SELECT amount FROM gift WHERE order_id=123456) Gift
```

Comment: The query you propose give's an error. I changed it a little to: **IFNULL(OrderTotal.total,0) + IFNULL(Shipping.amount,0) + IFNULL(Service.amount,0) - IFNULL(Gift.amount,0) - IFNULL(RMA.total,0) AS TotalCosts**, but that also doesn't return anything. It only says that my query was succesfull, but doesn't return anything.

Comment: Oh sorry, I  got the mistake, you need to use a group by also in the subqueries so atleast null will be returned. So your subqueries has to be like "SELECT amount FROM gift WHERE order_id=123456 **group by order_id**"